# Bash script to compare ip addresses from web and local file

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to bash and am still trying to figure some stuff out. Currently I'm writing a simple script to grab the ip address value from a website (via wget) and compare it with the address I already have stored on the machine to check for address changes. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentIp=$(cat /root/ip.log)
if "$currentIp" == $(wget -O - -q -nv --delete-after www.icanhazip.com)
then
    echo IP address is unchanged
else
    echo IP address has changed
fi
```

But, after running it, bash is replacing the variable `currentIp` with its value and then trying to run it as a command (I have replaced my ip address with x's in this example):

```
line 3: x.x.x.x: command not found
IP address has changed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little syntax error in your expression. Use this instead:

```
if [ "$currentIp" == $(wget -O - -q -nv --delete-after www.icanhazip.com) ] ;
```